# Is there any way to filter List by field value of first object in this list?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have huge list with logging objects and I need to take only first n entries based on first object field value (`list.get(0).getId()`)

I do this way:

```
List<Event> list = asList(
                new Event("id_1", "value_1" ...), 
                new Event("id_1", "value_2" ...), 
                new Event("id_1", "value_3" ...),
                new Event("id_2", "value_4" ...),
                new Event("id_2", "value_5" ...),
                new Event("id_2", "value_6" ...));
        String id = events.get(0).getId();
        return list.stream()
                .filter(event -> event.getId().equals(id))
                .collect(toList());
```

And it works, but it looks like not true way. Can you give me an advice how to do this better?

Comment: What makes you this is not the correct way?

Comment: @Sweeper list can be empty and i should check it. and i hope i can do it all in same stream

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the initial access to the list (to obtain the Id of the first event), you can group the events by Id, and return the first group of events:

```
return list.stream()
           .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Event::getId,
                                          LinkedHashMap::new,
                                          Collectors.toList()))
           .values()
           .iterator()
           .next();
```

P.S. if the list can be empty, you still have to check that `.values().iterator().hasNext()`.